# How to test regex value using jasmine

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, jasmine

Below Test code, throwing me an error "Can't find variable: $"

jQuery:

```
var NumericDecimal = (function (inputId) {
if ($(inputId).val().match(/[^0-9.]/g))
    $(inputId).val($(inputId).val().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')); });
```

Test Code:

```
describe("regex", function () {
it('has numeric and decimal only', function () {
    var value = "12345";
    expect(AllowNumericAndDecimalOnly($('#name'))).toHaveValue(value);
});});
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: If you change every `$` to `jQuery`, will it work?

Comment: yes I tried. But, it is not working.